# How can I show the interval in the output

Tags: java

I want to see my interval in the output and the couples that are in the interval.
For example

````
and then in the output:

interval a = 1,1,1,1,2,3,5,2,5
couples in interval a = 4 
the couples are = 1,1,1,1 // 2,2 // 3 // 5,5```

The code:  
[![The code][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ooiA.png
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post pictures of your code, instead post the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will code will formate the output as follow

- couples in intervals 3
- couples are : {1=3, 2=3, 3=2}

  ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] f = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2 };
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> pairs = countPair(f);
        System.out.println("couples in intervals " + pairs.size());
        System.out.print("couples are : " + pairs);
    }

    public static TreeMap<Integer, Integer> countPair(int[] arr) {
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int element : arr) {
            if (m.containsKey(element)) {
                m.put(element, m.get(element) + 1);
            } else {
                m.put(element, 1);
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
  ```

  }